# Postgres tablespace used up but no table is associated with it

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgres(14) database running on debian 11, one of the tablespace's directory if almost full, 98%. However, I have tried looking for tables on the said tablespace but none is there. Below command lists the tablespaces via psql

```
\db
                               List of tablespaces
             Name              |  Owner   |               Location
-------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------
 pg_default                    | postgres |
 pg_global                     | postgres |
 mydata                        | postgres | /data1/mydata_tablespace
 mydata_data2                  | postgres | /data2/mydata_data2_tablespace
 mydata_data3_tablespace       | postgres | /data3/mydata_data3_tablespace
```

I have tried looking for any tables withe below queries but none.

```
SELECT tablename 
FROM pg_tables WHERE tablespace='mydata_data2';
```

or

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename, indexname, tablespace
FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablespace='mydata_data2';
```

Comment: Files in the tablespace would have paths like " pg_tblspc/tablespace_oid/version/database_oid/relfilenode".  then use `select relname, relfilenode from pg_class where relfilenode=2688;`

Comment: @fukanchik,  This helped, happens that some table partitions were moved to the tablespace. I think

Answer (score 0):

One scenario is that there might be no tables in the `mydata_data2` tablespace, yet other objects such as indexes or sequences are using the tablespace. You can use the following query to list all objects that are using the `mydata_data2` tablespace

```sql
SELECT
    n.nspname AS schemaname,
    c.relname AS objectname,
    c.relfilenode AS filenodename,
    CASE c.relkind
        WHEN 'r' THEN 'table'
        WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence'
        WHEN 'v' THEN 'view'
        WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view'
        WHEN 'c' THEN 'composite type'
        WHEN 't' THEN 'TOAST table'
        ELSE c.relkind::text
    END AS objecttype
FROM pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.reltablespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_tablespace WHERE spcname = 'mydata_data2')
ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname;
```

SQL statements that were part of the experiment (for reproduction purposes)

```sql
--Create tablespace
CREATE TABLESPACE mydata_data2 OWNER root LOCATION '/content/mydata_data2';

-- Create a table inside the tablespace
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
) TABLESPACE mydata_data2;

-- Insert some dummy data into the table
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('Jane');
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('Bob');

-- One more table
CREATE TABLE ip_addresses2 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    network CIDR NOT NULL,
    description TEXT
) TABLESPACE mydata_data2;
```

This was the output

[image: Query Test]

An index and a TOAST table were created automatically. Perhaps the case on your end is similar and there might other objects occupying the space.

Comment: No object displayed.